# Inject external javascript code in JSNI

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni, android-pay

I am integrating Google Wallet on my GWT app. At some point (at beginning of JSNI function `purchase()`), I need to inject API JS code in my app.

```
<script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
```

How can I do it?

```
public static native void purchase(String token) /*-{
// Success handler
  var successHandler = function(status){
    if ($wnd.console != undefined) {
      console.log("Purchase completed successfully: ", status);
      //window.location.reload();
    }
  }

  // Failure handler
  var failureHandler = function(status){
    if ($wnd.console != undefined) {
      console.log("Purchase failed ", status);
    }
  }

  google.payments.inapp.buy({
        'jwt'     : token,
        'success' : successHandler,
        'failure' : failureHandler
    });
}-*/;
```

Comment: Not a java person, but I guess the question is "when" do you *need* to inject it and *why* (re: _perhaps_ it's just the trigger that needs injecting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject the code with a [ScriptInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html), because the GWT-code may run within a hidden IFRAME (depends on the used Linker)